# Laravel: update data through Request Validation is not updating data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on updating data in API endpoint. As, I am using Form Request Validation to keep the validation separate from Controller.

That works fine with the Store Request.

But, when I am trying to update a single data as mentioned below, the response is returning the following response data.

As, the data are already stored in database. When I send request for updating data.. that should return the updated data. But, It's not returning.

Need help to solve that.

JSON Data in Body:

```
{
    "title": "Question Changed 2"
}
```

Current Response:

```
{
  "question_type": [
    "Question Type is Required!"
  ],
  "question": [
    "Question is Required!"
  ],
  "is_required": [
    "Is Require Value is Required"
  ]
}
```

QuestionRequest:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'question_type' => 'required | min:3 | max:10',
            'title' => 'required | min:5 | max:100',
            'question' => 'required | min:5 | max:255',
            'description' => 'min:10 | max:255',
            'is_required' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Update:

```
public function update(QuestionRequest $request, Question $question)
    {
        $question = $question->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($question, 200);
    }
```

Comment: what are you expecting to be returned from your controller method? as `update` returns a boolean

Comment: @lagbox, I want to return the data, which has been updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the sometimes validation rule as mentioned in [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list

You can change the `rules` array as

```
        return [
            'question_type' => 'sometimes|required | min:3 | max:10',
            'title' => 'sometimes|required | min:5 | max:100',
            'question' => 'sometimes|required | min:5 | max:255',
            'description' => 'sometimes|min:10 | max:255',
            'is_required' => 'sometimes|required',
        ];
```

This way the validation on these fields will only be run if they are present in the request.

Comment: in that case.. i need to put a default value form fields.. which is not present in the array. What about, if I don't want to put a default value?

Comment: If you only update `title`, then you only need to send `title` in the Request Body. Laravel will only validate `title` and would not validate other fields. It will then update `title` related to Question Model.

Comment: In that case, that's working. But, my question is: when I am trying to store data and not putting the title in array: that demand a default value: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value(showing the error). How to deal with that?

Comment: Then you should make that column `nullable` in your migration.

Comment: if I put nullable in migration and required that field in Request Validation, That shows the same error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value

Comment: using sometimes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202001/discussion-between-tanjiya-and-ascsoftw).

Comment: Yes. I am using sometime in validation

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need the solution, I am updating the answer:

I have simply put the conditional logic in Request Validation Rules as following. Added ***sometime*** according to @[ascsoftw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309690/ascsoftw) for updating data.

```
public function rules()
    {
        switch($this->method())
        {
            case 'POST':
                {
                    return [
                        'question_type' => 'required | min:3 | max:10',
                        'title' => 'required | min:5 | max:100',
                        'question' => 'required | min:5 | max:255',
                        'description' => 'min:10 | max:255',
                        'is_required' => 'required',
                    ];
                }
                break;

            case 'PUT':
                {
                    return [
                        'question_type' => 'sometimes | required | min:3 | max:10',
                        'title' => 'sometimes | required | min:5 | max:100',
                        'question' => 'sometimes | required | min:5 | max:255',
                        'description' => 'sometimes | min:10 | max:255',
                        'is_required' => 'sometimes | required',
                    ];
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`return [
        'question_type' => 'sometimes|required | min:3 | max:10',
        'title' => 'sometimes|required | min:5 | max:100',
        'question' => 'sometimes|required | min:5 | max:255',
        'description' => 'sometimes|min:10 | max:255',
        'is_required' => 'sometimes|required',
    ];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).